# Location of EC2 instace storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just booted AWS EC2 instance type m3.medium which has 4GB of SSD instance storage. I could not find the 4GB directory. Where is it located at?

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the instance, you need to add the instance storage volumes explicitly in the "configure storage" tab of the launch wizard or equivalent settings in CLI/SDK. Then, according to your OS, you may see them automatically mapped to a new drive, automounted or ready to mount.

Mind that instance store volumes are ephemeral, i.e., they are erased when the instance is stopped.

For more information on instance storage, see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Elastic Beanstalk? It doesn't seem logical to manually attach storage to EC2 instances that are being booted and torn down automatically by EB.

Comment: It is, check the "Block Device Mappings" section at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html

Comment: Thanks Julio, I was able to do it and use the instance storage as swap using a .ebextensions script.